# The $body_bytes_sent variable should be equal to Content-Length?

Tags: nginx

Suppose the server response to a request always has a the `Content-Length` header and is not split into chunks.

Then [`$body_bytes_sent`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_body_bytes_sent) will be equal to `Content-Length` header. But what if the user couldn't read the entire request body? Can I log the number of bytes that nginx was supposed to send and how many bytes reached the client?

Answer (score 0):

To get `Content-length`, you can use the variable `$sent_http_content_length`.